# How to reverse a string using pointers in C

Tags: c

I have a char pointer that points to a string "hello". I need to reverse it without using `strev` function. I am new to the field of programming and am interested in doing it using pointers. There is ton of work on net using arrays. How do I achieve this?

```
char* arr = "hello";
stringRev(arr);
```

Comment: "doing it using pointers" What do you mean by that?

Comment: Looks like your teacher gave you a nice assignment to help you understand how pointers work, I just don't know how you are going to do that if someone else codes the damn thing for you.

Comment: String literal must not attempt to change.

Answer (score -1):

```
void stringRev(char* arr) {
    char* end = arr;
    while (*end)
        ++end;
    --end;
    while (arr < end) {
        char swap = *arr;
        *arr++ = *end;
        *end-- = swap;
    }
}
```

Comment: code-only answers are generally frowned upon, and assuming this is homework doing other people's homework with no explanation isn't that great for OP's progress, either.

Comment: (albeit I'll admit this code is a nice puzzle for someone who needs to learn pointer arithmetics)